# Confusion on a problem on limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is it true that $$lim_{n->\infty}(1-(0.75)^n)^{2^n} = 0$$ and
$$lim_{n->\infty}(1-(0.25)^n)^{2^n} = 1$$. Why ?

Comment: Yes. Because 0.25<1/2<0.75. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle y=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-x^n)^{2^n}$ where $|x|<1$

$$\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\ln(1-x^n)=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1-x^n)}{-x^n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}(2x)^n$$

As $\displaystyle|x|<1,\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1-x^n)}{-x^n}=1$

As $|x|<1, |2x|<2$

Now, if $\displaystyle|2x|<1\iff -0.5<x<0.5, \lim_{n\to\infty}(2x)^n=0\implies \ln y=0$

Else if $\displaystyle1<2x<2$ whence $\lim_{n\to\infty}(2x)^n=\infty\implies \ln y=-\infty$

Else if $\displaystyle1<-2x<2\iff-1>2x>-2$ whence $\lim_{n\to\infty}(2x)^n=-\infty\implies \ln y=+\infty$

Else $\displaystyle|2x|=1,$ I leave this as an exercise as this is not directly required in the current question.

Can you take it from here?